# YouTube API pause video on mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I'm creating a function which `inserts an YouTube video on hover` and then `on mouseeave the video is paused.` The problem is that `pause works only the first time.` Than if you click on the video and then when you leave div video i not paused anymore. I have trying binding the moueleave event but it still dosn't work, Thanks

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z5vfja46/

html:

```
<div class="video_wrap"><div id="one"></div></div>
<div class="video_wrap"><div id="two"></div></div>
<div class="video_wrap"><div id="three"></div></div>
<div class="video_wrap"><div id="four"></div></div>
```

js:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script'),
    firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;
$(".video_wrap").on({
    mouseenter: function () {

        player = new YT.Player($(this).children().attr('id'), {
            height: '240',
            width: '320',
            videoId: '-NschES-8e0',
            playerVars: {
            wmode: "transparent",
            controls: 0,
            showinfo: 0,
            rel: 0,
            modestbranding: 1,
            iv_load_policy: 3 //anottations
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady
            }
        });

        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            player.setVolume(0);
            event.target.playVideo();
        }

       $(this).children().bind( "mouseleave", function() {
           player.pauseVideo();
       });


    }
});
```

Comment: @intothev01d, not only a possible duplicate ... both questions are by the **same person**!!!

Comment: I think you should give this a try. https://www.fbijobs.gov/03.asp @Roamer-1888

Comment: @rexhin, so you think I'm not already a member? My disguise must be working.